# Changing Array Notation to pure pointer notations

Tags: c

I had this school project that I'm working on. I am done, I just need to edit it a bit and am running into a issue. I sent my code to my professor so he could check it over and there's only one thing wrong with it.

> All your array notations need to change to pure pointer notations such as `*s1` or `s1++`, etc.  nothing like `*(random + 41 - 1)` or `*(s2_input + count)` - you need to update your pointer and use dereference (exactly what you are doing in `strfilter` function.

He wouldn't explain further, so I am just confused on how exactly I would change my code. I have figured out my code is still in a array notation in a couple spots but any help would be appreciated.
Such as  `*(random + 41 - 1) = '\0';`  , `*(s2_input + count) = '\0';` , and `*(s2_input + count) = input;`. What can I do to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Function Prototypes*/
int main();
void s1(char *random);
void s2(char *s2_input, int index);
void strfilter(char *random, char *s2_input, char replacement);

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        int s1_index = 41;
        char s1_random[s1_index];
        s1(s1_random);
        printf("\ns1 = ");
        puts(s1_random);
        printf("s2 = ");
        int s2_index = 21;
        char s2_input[s2_index];
        s2(s2_input, s2_index);

        if(s2_input[1] == '\0')
        {
            printf("Size too small");
            exit(0);
        }

        if(s2_input[21] != '\0' )
        {
            printf("Size too big");
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("ch = ");
        int replacement = getchar();
        if(replacement == EOF)
            break;
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        printf("\n");
        strfilter(s1_random, s2_input, replacement);
        printf("\ns1 filtered = ");
        puts(s1_random);

        printf("Do you wish to run again? Yes(Y), No(N) ");
        int run = getchar();
        // or include ctype.h and do:
        // run == EOF || toupper(run) == 'N'
        if(run == EOF || run == 'N' || run == 'n')
            break;
        while(getchar() != '\n');

    }
}




void s1(char *random)
{
    int limit = 0;
    char characters;
    while((characters = (('A' + (rand() % 26))))) /* random generatro */
    {
        if(limit == 41)
        {
            *(random + 41 - 1) = '\0';
            break;
        }
        *(random + limit) = characters;
        limit++;
    }
}



void s2(char *s2_input, int index)
{
    char array[21] = "123456789012345678901"; /* populated array to make sure no random memory is made */
    char input;
    int count = 0;
    int check = 0;

    while((input = getchar() ))
    {
        if(input == '\n')
        {
            *(s2_input + count) = '\0';
            break;
        }

        else if(input < 65 || input > 90)
        {
            printf("invalid input");
            exit(0);
        }

        *(s2_input + count) = input;
        count++;
    }

    index = count;
}

void strfilter(char *random, char *s2_input, char replacement) /* replacement function */
{
    while(*s2_input)
    {
        char *temp = random;

        while(*temp)
        {
            if(*temp == *s2_input)
                *temp = replacement;
            temp++;
        }
        s2_input++;
    }
}
```

I tried a making a temporary pointer and replacing it with the array notation but I still would need to have the array notation somewhere. I can have the array defined somewhere but that's it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I just got clarification from the professor on what he wants.
You don't have to initialize s2 as an array you can initialize it as pointer to integer (int s2;) then you can do a pointer to an array (int (s1)[41];) then point to the single element of the array by doing this: s2 = s1; and incriminating to the next element by doing this: s2++

Does this make sense to anyone? I understand that he wants me to make a int pointer, and then use that to point to a certain element in the array however I am not sure on how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted this as that you need to replace

`*(random + limit) = characters;`

with

```
*random++=characters;
```

and

```
*(s2_input + count) = input;
```

becomes

```
*s2_input++ = input;
```

i.e. he is asking you to move the pointer to the next point as you use it rather than recalculate each time.

Below are 3 ways of doing the same thing.

```
void s1(char *random)
{

    for(int limit=0;limit<40;++limit)
    {
       char characters = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
       // random[limit]=characters;
       // *(random + limit) = characters;
       *random++=characters;
    }
    // random[limit]='\0';
    // *(random + limit) = '\0';
    *random='\0';

}
```

Comment: This doesn't run correctly. I just checked and it won't output the correct string.

Comment: I'm showing you the idea, not writing the code for you.  I am not even sure my interpretation is correct.

Comment: maybe he wants me to create a pointer which then points to the array at a specific location? Or am I just completely off.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. Hardwiring the limit in `s1` is bad. Better to pass the max length as an arg.
2. The "Size too big" check in `main` *must* be done in `s2` to prevent overflow/UB.

---

Here is the refactored code. I just fixed the pointer usage, but didn't test otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Function Prototypes*/
int main();
#if 0
void s1(char *random);
#else
void s1(char *random,int maxlen);
#endif
#if 0
void s2(char *s2_input, int index);
#else
int s2(char *s2_input, int index);
#endif
void strfilter(char *random, char *s2_input, char replacement);

int
main()
{
    for (;;) {
        int s1_index = 41;
        char s1_random[s1_index];

        s1(s1_random,s1_index);
        printf("\ns1 = ");
        puts(s1_random);

        printf("s2 = ");
        int s2_index = 21;
        char s2_input[s2_index];

#if 0
        s2(s2_input, s2_index);
        if (s2_input[1] == '\0') {
            printf("Size too small");
            exit(0);
        }
#else
        int len = s2(s2_input, s2_index);
        if (len < 2) {
            printf("Size too small\n");
            exit(0);
        }
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: the s2 function has to check this -- if too much data entered,
// s2 will overflow the buffer before we get here (causing UB)
#if 0
        if (s2_input[21] != '\0') {
            printf("Size too big");
            exit(0);
        }
#endif

        printf("ch = ");
        int replacement = getchar();
        if (replacement == EOF)
            break;

        while (getchar() != '\n');

        printf("\n");
        strfilter(s1_random, s2_input, replacement);

        printf("\ns1 filtered = ");
        puts(s1_random);

        printf("Do you wish to run again? Yes(Y), No(N) ");
        int run = getchar();

        // or include ctype.h and do:
        // run == EOF || toupper(run) == 'N'
        if (run == EOF || run == 'N' || run == 'n')
            break;
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    }
}

void
s1(char *random,int maxlen)
{
#if 0
    int limit = 0;
    char characters;

    /* random generatro */
    while ((characters = (('A' + (rand() % 26))))) {
        if (limit == 41) {
            *(random + 41 - 1) = '\0';
            break;
        }
        *(random + limit) = characters;
        limit++;
    }
#else
    char characters;

    /* random generatro */
    for (--maxlen;  maxlen > 0;  --maxlen) {
        characters = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
        *random++ = characters;
    }

    *random = 0;
#endif
}

#if 0
void
s2(char *s2_input, int maxlen)
{
    /* populated array to make sure no random memory is made */
    char array[21] = "123456789012345678901";
    char input;
    int count = 0;
    int check = 0;

    while ((input = getchar())) {
        if (input == '\n') {
            *(s2_input + count) = '\0';
            break;
        }

        else if (input < 65 || input > 90) {
            printf("invalid input");
            exit(1);
        }

        *(s2_input + count) = input;
        count++;
    }

    index = count;
}
#else
int
s2(char *s2_input, int maxlen)
{
    int input;
    int count = 0;

    --maxlen;

    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (input == '\n')
            break;

        if (input < 65 || input > 90) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        if (maxlen <= 0) {
            printf("input too long\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        *s2_input++ = input;
        --maxlen;
        ++count;
    }

    *s2_input = 0;

    return count;
}
#endif

/* replacement function */
void
strfilter(char *random, char *s2_input, char replacement)
{
    while (*s2_input) {
        char *temp = random;

        while (*temp) {
            if (*temp == *s2_input)
                *temp = replacement;
            temp++;
        }
        s2_input++;
    }
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Comment: I'm not sure what the clarification means. `s2` is a _function_, so do you mean `s1_input`? I believe my code changes handle the pointer manipulation already. Otherwise, this is something that changes the program functionality. That is, I'm not sure how using `int *` helps anything.